# Spring @Transactional is not commited. Neo4J

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data

I have an entity User that has relationship WORKS_FOR with an entity Organization. Organization has relationship HAS_EMPLOYEE with all users that are in and a relationship HAS_ANCHOR, with one anchor for the whole organization to manage it. I am trying to update organization entity with another user from "HAS_EMPLOYEE" list to become a new anchor. But there are no changes in db after the method and no runtime exceptions are thrown.

```
@Transactional
public OrganizationDTO changeAnchorForOrganization(UUID prevAnchorId, UUID newAnchorId) {
    User newAnchor = userService.getAnyUserById(newAnchorId);
    if (!newAnchor.isActive()) {
        throw new BadRequestException(ExceptionType.REQUEST_BODY_INVALID);
    }
    User prevAnchor = userService.getAnyUserById(prevAnchorId);
    Organization organization = getOrganizationByAnchorId(prevAnchorId);
    Set<String> prevAnchorPermissions = prevAnchor.getPermissions();
    prevAnchorPermissions.remove(SubRolesConstants.anchor);
    prevAnchor.setPermissions(prevAnchorPermissions);
    Set<String> newAnchorPermissions = newAnchor.getPermissions();
    newAnchorPermissions.add(SubRolesConstants.anchor);
    newAnchor.setPermissions(newAnchorPermissions);
    organization.setAnchor(newAnchor);
    return organizationMapper.entityToDTO(organization);
}
```

**organization.setAnchor(newAnchor);** this line is not working?
The result DTO has the changes made to org anchor but db is not. And if i'll try to get the ogranization after this method i'll get the old version of organization(with previous anchor)
Stuck with that for a long time. Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: What version of Spring Data Neo4j are you using?
Also, I don't see any service call in your code to save the changes.

Comment: i thought @transactional operates with managed entities so they will be saved by the entity manager at the end of the transaction. The version of spring data neo4j is 2.3.2 RELEASE

Comment: Spring Data Neo4j 2? Are you sure? This has not been maintained for years. Can you extract the version from `mvn dependency:tree`?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing **organizationRepository.save(organization)**.I think it's because of neo4j because by default @Transactional annotation commit any changes made to entities at the end of the service call. Or it's just a bug.